# if memory_limit is 128M , then any script will use 128MB RAM?

Tags: php

if i set memory_limit is 128MB. I run a index.php:

```
<?php
echo 1;
?>
```

then this script use 128MB RAM ? I think it is not , but want make sure it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it doesn't. 128 MB is just the maximum a script can use, it doesn't necessarily HAVE TO use 128 MB. But it won't be allowed to use anymore than that.

Answer (score 3):

From [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) (emphasis mine):

> This sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that a script **is allowed to allocate**.